# Change background color on elements with the same color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, background-color

I'm trying to create a simple theme system here. I have few elements with red background color. I also have a button that will change the elements background color to green.

I'm trying to code but I couldn't figure out how can I select and change the bg color of all red elements to green!

For example, I have 4 divs. Two of these have a red header, and when I click the button these headers background color must be changed to green. It's Ok here, but the problem is that the divs are dynamically generated, so do I have do loop all the page to find the red bg color? Could someone enlight me? =)

Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: you'll have to iterate through every element, although it can me managed using a custom jQuery selector.

Comment: I think you'd be better off having `red` and `green` class. And adding/removing those classes as needed. Would also make selecting those elements that need changing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use different stylesheet for each theme and keep the current theme value in SESSION or COOKIE or just pass it as URL argument. But that would be a server side solution.
On Client side, you can just use different classes for each theme and toggle them on the button push event using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('.green').toggleClass('red green');
```

Comment: For red one you will use `$('.red').toggleClass('red green')`

Comment: Nice one Mika! The solution I wrote was very similar to yours but anyway it worked! I'll think about store the current theme on Cookie or Session as you suggested!
Thanks a lot! =]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to have a specific CSS class for each background color you're using. ex:

```
.color-red{ background-color: #FF0000; }
.color-green{ background-color: #00FF00; }
```

Once you do that you can select on the CSS class as well as set the CSS class:

```
$('#button-togreen').click(function(){
  $('.color-red').removeClass('color-red').addClass('color-green');
}
```

It's kind of a round-about way of doing it, however there is no easy way to select on a CSS attribute (to do that you'd have to select all elements of the page and then check each one of them for the background color attribute which would be scarily inefficient...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by headers, but I think this should do what you want:

```
$('.myDivs').filter(function(index){
  return $(this).css('color') == 'red';
}).css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: OK, class-based answers are better, now that I think of it.